# How to sort my users by field in an array ? mongoose

Tags: node.js, sorting, mongoose, aggregate

i have this model user

**Model : users**

```
   u_email: String,
   u_password: String,
   u_displayed:Boolean,
   u_info:[
    {
        pi_id:{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'wt_infos'},
        key:String,
        value:String,


    }],
```

**Example**

```
"u_info" : [ 
    {
       "value" : "200",
        "key" : "budget",
        "pi_id" : ObjectId("5adf5bb8c7091c39300223cd")
    }, 
    {
        "value" : "23/02/2019",
        "key" : "date",
        "pi_id" : ObjectId("5adf5bb8c7091c39300223cf")
    },
```

How to sort my users, by my field "budget" that should be converted to int and have this id **5adf5bb8c7091c39300223cd** using aggregate

Comment: You could use `$sort` operator [doc here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/)

Comment: it's not a simple sort, because it's string to be converted to float and it will be called by id